# Thread-safe ring buffer for producers-consumer in C

Tags: c, data-structures, buffer

In C, I have **several threads producing** `long` values, and **one thread consuming** them. Therefore I need a buffer of a fixed size implemented in a similar fashion to i.e. the [Wikipedia implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#Difficulties), and methods that access it in a thread-safe manner.

On a general level, the following should hold:

- When adding to a full buffer, the thread should be blocked (no overwriting old values).
- The consumer thread should be blocked until the buffer is full - it's job has a high constant cost, and should do as much work as possible. (Does this call for a double-buffered solution?)

I would like to use a tried implementation, preferably from a library. Any ideas?

---

Motivation & explanation:

I am writing JNI code dealing with deleting [global references](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html) kept as [tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#Heap) in heap objects.

When a `ObjectFree` JVMTI event occurs, I get a `long` tag representing a global reference I need to free using `DeleteGlobalRef`. For this, I need a `JNIEnv` reference - and getting it is **really** costly, so I want to buffer the requests and remove as many as possible at once.

There might be many threads receiving the `ObjectFree` event, and there will be one thread (mine) doing the reference deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single buffer, with a mutex when accessed. You'll need to keep track of how many elements are used. For "signaling", you can use condition variables. One that is triggered by the producer threads whenever they place data in the queue; this releases the consumer thread to process the queue until empty. Another that is triggered by the consumer thread when it has emptied the queue; this signals any blocked producer threads to fill the queue. For the consumer, I recommend locking the queue and taking out as much as possible before releasing the lock (to avoid too many locks), especially since the dequeue operation is simple and fast.

**Update**
A few useful links:
* [Wikipedia explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29)
* [POSIX Threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables)
* [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

a) malloc() a *Buffer struct with an array to hold some longs and an index - no locking required.  Have each producer thread malloc its own *Buffer and start loading it up.  When a producer thread fills the last array position, queue the *Buffer to the consumer thread on a producer-consumer queue and immediately malloc() a new *Buffer.  The consumer gets the *Buffers and processes them and then free()s them, (or queues them off somewhere else, or pushes them back onto a pool for re-use by producers).  This avoids any locks on the buffers themselves, leaving only the lock on the P-C queue.  The snag is that producers that only occasionally generate their longs will not get their data processed until their *Buffer gets filled up, which may take some time, (you could push off the Buffer before the array gets full, in such a thread.

b) Declare a Buffer struct with an array to hold some longs and an index. Protect with a mutex/futex/CS lock. malloc() just one shared *Buffer and have all the threads get the lock, push on their long and release the lock.  If a thread pushes in the last array position, queue the *Buffer to the consumer thread on a producer-consumer queue,  immediately malloc a new *Buffer and then release the lock.  The consumer gets the *Buffers and processes them and then free()s them, (or queues them off somewhere else, or pushes them back onto a pool for re-use by producers).

Comment: Hi, thanks, unfortunately my C is not good enough to know whether your answer is really for C - it seems to be for C++. Could you please clarify?

Comment: OOPS!!!!!!!!!  Will substitute 'struct' for 'class', 'malloc()' for 'new', 'free()', for delete() in an edit.  My bad:((

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take condition in consideration. Take a look at this piece of code for consumer :

```
while( load == 0 )
    pthread_cond_wait( &notEmpty, &mutex );
```

What it does is to check to see whether load ( where you store the number of elements in your list ) is zero or not and if it is zero, it'll wait until producer produces new item and put it in the list.
You should implement the same condition for producer ( when it wants to put item in a full list )